# Relation between High government debt to GDP ratio, financial stability of a country and repricing effect on balance sheet of banks

Tags: taxation, government-debt, fiscal-policy, pricing, public-debt

Was reading an editorial in which author wrote following:-
[image]

I understood it as follows:

India having High Debt/GDP(around 84%), means Foreign portfolio investors(FPIs) will have less confidence to invest in our economy because FPIs will think that it(india) is unable to finance it's debts and most of revenue it(india) raises goes into paying interest amount on debts and less on spending into various economic and social purposes. So in nutshell this implies yes there is financial stability risk (even sovereign default risk would be there if india's most of debt was denominated in currency other than it's domestic currency(INR), say USD, but thankfully it is not).

But What I do not understand Is how High Debt/GDP is affecting balance sheet of banks and how it is related to repricing of assets of the bank, after interest risen. I infact what is the point author is making in whole this paragraph, please help me understand this. I am attaching image of hardcopy of whole article down below:

[image]

Thanks for your resposne.

Clarification about term:SLR(statutory liquidity ratio)

In india Our central bank (Called reserve bank of india or RBI) mandates all other banks to keep some money aside with themselves in the form of Government securities, gold etc and shouldn't lend out all the money, to prevent the bank run i.e., or we can say How much money can bank not lend out is quantfied by metric called SLR(Statutory liquidity ratio) it is some percentage of net time and demand liabilities(NDTL) that bank can not loan out to customers.